# How to feed LibVNCServer library with an image of IWICBitmap type on windows platform?

Tags: c++, windows, vnc, vnc-server

I am creating a VNC Server using libvncServer library. I have captured the screenshot of screen which is in IWICBitmap structure. I need to assign this image to the libVNCServer.
I am new to c++ environment so not able to do it...

I am trying to take out the buffer into a Unsigned char* buffer. But IWICBitmap->copyPixel api is giving following error. Insufficient buffer size.

Thanks in advance.